# Ubuntu 16.04 on MacBook Air 2009 - WiFi, suspend and touch-pad

Tags: 16.04, wireless, touchpad, macbook-air

I have something that is wrong on my system : everything seems to work fine, but then I realized that I couldn't detect any WiFi networks. I installed everything I think I needed such as Broadcom 4321 drivers etc...

After few hours I closed the MacBook, and then, I saw a message saying "Wifi networks are available..." After I opened it, so I went to the network settings and I was able to detect WiFi networks! But the touch-pad wasn't working.

So, to resume : WiFi only works after suspend, but the touch-pad doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work because I found it on the internet and is not a first-hand thing, but you might want to give it a try. The solution was not install mtrack and edit a configuration file:

1) install

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack
```

2) at the bottom of configuration add those settings

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf


Section "InputClass"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Identifier      "Touchpads"
        Driver          "mtrack"
        Option          "Sensitivity" "0.95"
        Option          "FingerHigh" "12"
        Option          "FingerLow" "1"
        Option          "IgnoreThumb" "true"
        Option          "IgnorePalm" "true"
        Option          "TapButton1" "0"
        Option          "TapButton2" "0"
        Option          "TapButton3" "0"
        Option          "TapButton4" "0"
        Option          "ClickFinger1" "1"
        Option          "ClickFinger2" "3"
        Option          "ClickFinger3" "3"
        Option          "ButtonMoveEmulate" "false"
        Option          "ButtonIntegrated" "true"
        Option          "ClickTime" "25"
        Option          "BottomEdge" "25"
        Option          "SwipeLeftButton" "8"
        Option          "SwipeRightButton" "9"
        Option          "SwipeUpButton" "0"
        Option          "SwipeDownButton" "0"
        Option          "ScrollDistance" "75"
        Option          "ScrollUpButton" "5"
        Option          "ScrollDownButton" "4"
EndSection
```

I hope this works for your. I am not sure about the rules regarding posting links but I feel the need to give creds to the original poster [here](http://yarenty.blogspot.nl/2014/08/how-to-fix-macbook-pro-touchpad-on.html)

I am still not quite sure about your wifi. So, is it working now or still not working? Because I am also working on a Mac and didn't have to install any drives.

**Update** An easier solution that I just tried on my laptop (might not work for your, but let's hope it does!)

```
System settings > Mouse&Touchpad > and turn the touchpad on if it is off.
```

Comment: Thank you, but it only stop working after suspend. I tried the first solution which desn't work. I will try the second One, but I think it might not work either, because it works well before I close the MacBook. Thank you again !