# Ubuntu Touchpad / USB Mouse Click Event Not Working

Tags: mouse, suspend, touchpad, tap-to-click

I cant able to use my Touch pad as well us USB mouse once i suspend or put my laptop on hibernate. how do i fix it?

once laptop went sleep i cant able perform Button Click using Touch Pad / USB Mouse.. even my laptop having touch screen that too not working. only Button Click event. otherwise scrolling and all works fine..

Comment: Does it work after restarting?

Comment: yes only once... then it start to behave same

Comment: similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/862244/ubuntu-16-04-on-macbook-air-2009-wifi-suspend-and-touch-pad https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154997/mouse-network-turned-off-after-suspend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508929/touchpad-unresponsive-on-resume-from-sleep-on-debian-8/65886286

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution how i solved it,

http://sourcedigit.com/21687-ubuntu-usb-mouse-not-working-ubuntu-touchpad-not-working/

Comment: The answer recommends to: check if the touchpad is listed in /proc/bus/input/devices; `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`; or edit /etc/default/grub

Answer (score 0):

**suggestions:**

`modprobe -r i2c-hid; modprobe i2c-hid;` from

- http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=128952

`modprobe -r psmouse; modprobe psmouse;` from

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508929/touchpad-unresponsive-on-resume-from-sleep-on-debian-8/65886286
- https://matoski.com/article/debian-touchpad-not-working/ ;
- https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad#Touchpad_does_not_work_after_resuming_from_hibernate.2Fsuspend

When anything from above works, automate it in a file in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` as shown in question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508929/touchpad-unresponsive-on-resume-from-sleep-on-debian-8

Comment: alternative file location: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ as shown in https://askubuntu.com/questions/671910/touchpad-not-working-after-suspending-laptop